# Change button text value for on_press event in Kivy

Tags: kivy

My application has a single  button with text value as '2'. I want to change the text value to 100 on `on_press` event

My attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.2')

from random import random
from random import choice
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

r1c2=random()
Builder.load_string("""
<Highest>:
    r1c2: str(2)
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Button:
            text: root.r1c2
            on_press: root.new()
""")

class Highest(Screen):
    def new(self):
        r1c2=str(100)


# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Highest(name='Highest'))

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Error: Currently, nothing happens when the button is pressed. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using kivy properties available. See [kivy.properties](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html) for more information.

Add this import for access to string property:

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
```

And your `Highest` class should be:

```
class Highest(Screen):
    r1c2 = StringProperty(str(2))

    def new(self):
        self.r1c2 = str(100)
```

At initialization `r1c2` value is equal to '2'. When the function `new()` is called value of `r1c2` will become '100'. Button text is bind to the string property `r1c2` so it will automatically change.

You don't need `r1c2=str(2)` in your builder string.

```
Builder.load_string("""
<Highest>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Button:
            text: root.r1c2
            on_press: root.new()
""")
```